# how do i assign a query into a variable inside a procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

i am currently trying to write a procedure which returns the number of contracts a customer has in a specific month,as well the total cost he need to pay in that month. For that it gets an integer(AFM1) and a date(DATE1) to idetify the client and the specific month. The tables i use for the procedure are the following:

````
```+------------------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+
| PRODUCT_TYPE           | START_DATE | END_DATE   | COST | contract_code |
+------------------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+
| CAR_INSURANCE          | 2021-01-01 | 2021-12-31 |  650 |             1 |
| HEALTH_INSURANCE       | 2021-01-01 | 2021-12-31 | 1000 |             2 |
| CRITICAL_ILLNESS_COVER | 2021-03-12 | 2021-09-30 |  600 |             3 |
| HOME_INSURANCE         | 2021-06-06 | 2022-06-06 | 1500 |             4 |
| CAR_INSURANCE          | 2021-02-02 | 2022-02-02 |  650 |             5 |
| CAR_INSURANCE          | 2021-03-03 | 2022-03-03 |  650 |             6 |
+------------------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+
6 rows in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [general_insurance]> select 8from customer_has_contract#
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '8from' in 'field list'
MariaDB [general_insurance]> select * from customer_has_contract#
+----------+------------------------+------+----------------------------------+
| AFM      | PRODUCT_TYPE           | CODE | total_cost_of_customer_contracts |
+----------+------------------------+------+----------------------------------+
| 19390194 | CAR_INSURANCE          |    1 |                                0 |
| 19390162 | HEALTH_INSURANCE       |    2 |                                0 |
| 19390161 | CRITICAL_ILLNESS_COVER |    3 |                                0 |
| 19390011 | HOME_INSURANCE         |    4 |                                0 |
| 19390161 | CAR_INSURANCE          |    5 |                                0 |
| 19390212 | CAR_INSURANCE          |    6 |                                0 |
+----------+------------------------+------+----------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.000 sec)```
````

and the procedure i wrote is this:

````
```CREATE PROCEDURE PROC1 (IN AFM1 INT, IN DATE1 DATE,OUT NMC INT,OUT TCM FLOAT)
    -> begin
    -> DECLARE M INT
    -> SET M := (SELECT MONTH(DATE1));
    -> SET NMC := (SELECT COUNT(CONTRACT_CODE) FROM CONTRACT JOIN CUSTOMER_HAS_CONTRACT ON CONTRACT.CONTRACT_CODE=CUSTOMER_HAS_CONTRACT.CODE WHERE START_DATE=M OR END_DATE=M AND AFM=AFM1);
    -> SET TCM := (SELECT COST(SUM) FROM CONTRACT JOIN CUSTOMER_HAS_CONTRACT ON CONTRACT.CONTRACT_CODE=CUSTOMER_HAS_CONTRACT.CODE WHERE START_DATE=M OR END_DATE=M AND AFM=AFM1);
    -> END
    -> #```
````

However when finish writting the procedure i get the following error:

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET M := (SELECT MONTH(DATE1));
SET NMC := (SELECT COUNT(CONTRACT_CODE) FROM ...' at line 4**

my question here is does `:=` also work in a procedure, when we want to store a query's value in a variable or does it work only in function?

thanks in advance

Comment: how to use [user definined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html)

Comment: There is a missing ; before the set M statement. The answers to the duplicate question show you how to the value assignment properly.